# Why Promise.all cannot work after all asynchronous function are completed?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, es6-promise

Hi I'm new to Js and I'd like to wait some async functions complete before print `ni`. But the code never print it I cannot understand why. Please help me:(

```
// public function
this.run = function() {
    'use strict';
    let compile_lib = lib_array.map((item) => {
        return new Promise(() => {compileEntry(item);})
    });
    Promise.all(compile_lib).then(() => { console.log("ni"); });
}
```

Comment: Your promise should take arguments (resolve, reject). Thanks to these arguments you'll be able to "say" the promise succeeded or failed. So you have to call the resolve method inside your promises ;) Tell me if it helps :)

Comment: I should also point out that if compileEntry is simply a long-running function, you won't be able to write it asynchronously without looking into something like Web Workers. The exact way you'd do this depends on the JavaScript environment. For browsers it would be web workers, or possibly something using setTimeout and doing parts of the compile in incremenets. If this calls a core third-party function that has some kind of "callback" or "onload" argument, then you can use that.

Answer (score 1):

> The Promise.all(iterable) method returns a promise that resolves when
>   all of the promises in the iterable argument have **resolved**, or **rejects**
>   with the reason of the first passed promise that rejects.

In your example, you didn't resolve or reject your Promises:

```
let compile_lib = lib_array.map((item) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => { compileEntry(item); })
});
```

please note the arguments `resolve`, `reject`. You should use these callbacks either to resolve or reject the promise. For example:

```
new Promise((resolve, reject) => { 
    var result = compileEntry(item);
    if(result) {
        resolve(result);
    }else {
        reject("reson");
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `resolve` and `reject`

> new Promise( /* executor */ function(resolve, reject) { ... } );

```js
var lib_array = [1, 2, 3];

function compileEntry(item, index) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(function() {
      resolve(console.log(item));
    }, index * 1000);
  });
}

this.run = function() {
  'use strict';
  let compile_lib = lib_array.map((item, index) => {
    return compileEntry(item, index);
  });
  Promise.all(compile_lib).then(() => {
    console.log("ni");
  });
}

this.run();
```